# Where do libraries come from that are in npm-shrinkwrap but don't correspond to package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

I have an `npm-shrinkwrap` file with `express` in it as a main dependency.

However,

- I don't have `express` as a dependency in my `package.json` file.
- I don't see it used in my project anywhere.
- I don't see it as a dependency of something else in `npm-shrinkwrap` which is what I would expect.

These are the possible reasons I can think of for it existing...

I've run the following and the library is still there:

```
npm prune
npm shrinkwrap
```

I ended up finding the dependency somewhere in `node_modules` but shouldn't it be listed as a dependency of that library in `npm-shrinkwrap` if it isn't explicitly a dependency of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package.json just lists your dependencies. But the packages you are using do have dependencies themselves. One of your packages is using express, which is why its in you node_modules folder.

Comment: This seems counter-intuitive, it makes it harder to know where a dependency comes from... I found in my `node_modules` under browserify, but it's not immediately clear, is there an advantage to this that I don't understand?

Comment: Im sure there are some tools, which read the package.json files from each module in your node_modules folder. But I myself did have my fair share of problems because of this. But don't know.